# Supersized - get title of previous / next slide?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is there a way to get the title of previous or next slide in supersized.js plugin? [API](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#themes_doc) allows to get the title only of current slide.

Thanks!

Comment: The API does not provide such an action -- read the source and write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currentSlide = vars.current_slide, // zero-based index
    slides = api.options.slides,
    totalSlides = slides.length - 1,

    nextSlideTitle = api.options.slides[ (currentSlide + 1 < totalSlides) ? currentSlide + 1 : 0 ].title,
    prevSlideTitle = api.options.slides[ (currentSlide - 1 > 0) ? currentSlide - 1 : totalSlides ].title;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But still can't get how to update it on slide change.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with the titles, so I just showed you how to get them. Where are these titles being updated to?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. Basically they should be shown in #next / #prev divs. Thanks!